# How to give space between the react-bootstrap accordions when dynamic data is given to it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-context

i have used a react-bootstrap accordion. I have done an api call to populate dynamic data within the accordion by mapping the data.Its background color is white and if i use a break tag to break between the accordions everything becomes white.you can't figure they are different accordions.
i want to modify the accordion properties using css.My two main concern here are 
1) to give space between accordions.
2) when i click on one accordion header all the accordions opens.
Following is my piece of code for accordion:

```
<Accordion className="accordion-length" >


       stateCategory.categories !== undefined ?(

      stateCategory.categories.map((cat)=>{
         return (
          <Card className="card-style">

          <Accordion.Toggle id="Accordion" as={Card.Header}  className=" back card-style " style={{top: "5px"}}>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;{cat.name}


           <Link onClick={()=>{handleBlock(cat)}}> 
           <img
            alt="block"
            src={require("../../assets/block.svg")}
            className="images" />
            </Link>
            <Link onClick={()=>{handleDelete(cat)}} >
              <img
            alt="delete"
            src={require("../../assets/delete.svg")}
            className="images" /></Link>

           <Link onClick={()=>{handleSubCategoryCreate(cat)}}> 
            <img
            alt="add "
            src={require("../../assets/add.svg")}
            className="images" /></Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>{handleEdit(cat)}}>
               <img
            alt="edit "
            src={require("../../assets/edit.svg")}
            className="images" /></Link>
       </Accordion.Toggle>

        <Accordion.Collapse style={{whiteSpace : "pre"}}>
          <Card.Body> 
            <ul>
            {(cat.jobSubCategories) && 
            cat.jobSubCategories.map((subCat)=>{

            return  <li key={subCat.id}>{subCat.name}
              <Link onClick={()=>{handleSubBlock(subCat)}}> 
                <img
            alt="block"
            src={require("../../assets/block.svg")}
            className="images" />
            </Link>
           <Link onClick={()=>{handleSubCategoryDelete(subCat)}}>  
            <img
            alt="delete"
            src={require("../../assets/delete.svg")}
            className="images" />
            </Link>


              <Link onClick={()=>{handleSubEdit(subCat)}}> 
              <img
            alt="edit "
            src={require("../../assets/edit.svg")}
            className="images" />
            </Link>
              </li>
            })

              }
            </ul>

          </Card.Body>

        </Accordion.Collapse>

      </Card>

         )
       })
       ):<></>
     }

</Accordion>
```